# Running npm start keeps the process running on the current port regardless of ending it

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I have my application running an a port:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '9999');
app.set('port', port);
```

For simplicity sake, I've just ran Express in a directory and created a brand new express application.

Issue: I run `npm start` to start my application. It runs fine, i've not got a gulp task setup. So I press `ctrl` + `c` to cancel, make my changes and run `npm start` again.

I then get an error like this:

```
Port 9999 is already in use

npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! example_test@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

So my process is still running on port 9999, how do I kill the process without needing to find the process and kill it every time. Isn't there a way I can cancel the process and it kills it at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`npm start` only runs a [start script for a package](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start).

Use `node <initialization file>` to start your Express app. For example: `node server.js`